# Use dictionary key for getElementById

Tags: javascript

I've stored cookie information in a dictionary to be recalled, but I am having trouble using the keys to find elements within the page. When I run the below code, the information gets stored from the cookie in the dictionary fine. I can output the dictionary information into the console and everything looks fine for that as well. When I try to use the key, the element cannot be found, but when I hardcode span variable with the element's id (as in var span = document.getElementById('bar');) it works fine. Initially, I thought it was a casting issue or something, so I tried String(key), but that didn't work either. Is it a type issue? An incorrect reference? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```js
var dict = {};
function foo() {
    //Break cookie into dictionary
    var keyValuePairs = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < keyValuePairs.length; i++) {
        var name = keyValuePairs[i].substring(0, keyValuePairs[i].indexOf('='));
        var value = keyValuePairs[i].substring(keyValuePairs[i].indexOf('=')+1);
        dict[name] = value;
    }
    
    //Search for elements using key value
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dict)) {
        var span = document.getElementById(key);
        if(span) {
            console.log("Element found named " + key);
        } else {
            console.log(key + " element not found.");
        }
        console.log(key, value);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure, your markup has the proper IDs? At first glance, the JS code looks fine to me. Also, could you show the logs for `dict`? Is that value as expected?

Comment: what do you get if you `console.log(key)` right under your `for(const [key, value] of ...)` loop

Comment: @pai.not.pi I hardcoded the span to make sure I could find the elements without the variables and that worked fine. Logs for the key value pairs for the dict log as expect.

Comment: @NickParsons I put the log statement right under the for statement and the console logs show the key values fine. There are no appended or prepended characters or anything like that.

Comment: @Jeremy Tried to replicate what you're trying to achieve here - https://jsfiddle.net/6xq3ak79/ - seems to be working fine.

Comment: Time to eat my words, I guess. I highlighted the log files and did see a prepended space before each of the keys. When I changes the split statements from "substring(0" to "substring(1", the prepended space was no longer an issue. I assumed unintentional characters wasn't an issue because I had added periods to either side of the values when I printed them to the logs and the periods were tight around the values.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was unintentional inclusion of space character resulting from

```
.substring(0, keyValuePairs[i].indexOf('='));
```

I changed it to

```
.substring(1, keyValuePairs[i].indexOf('='));
```

and it worked fine. All keys now contain only the intended value instead off "' 'value."

Comment: .substring(0, keyValuePairs[i].trim().indexOf('='));